# Javascript and Media Queries show hide hidden divs

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, media-queries

Does any one know how to use javascript with a media query?

I am wanting a left column menu which is hidden in mobile view using the bootstap 3 hidden-xs but I want to be able to click a menu button which overlays the left column over the main content area - which an x to close the menu. using

```
function showFunction()
    {
    document.getElementById("left-col").style.visibility="visible";
    }
    function hideFunction()
    {
    document.getElementById("left-col").style.visibility="hidden";
    }
```

When testing this in a broswer this works OK but once I have clicked the cross to close the menu if I resize the screen to desktop or above the break point of the media query the left-col remains hidden.

Is there anyway around this? Or is it a waste of time trying and the benefit of this would work on a mobile rather than users on desktops resizing browsers.

**Update** --

In Desktop view I have 3 columns left Main Right with a header and a footer.

In Mobile I am stacking the right colum under the main hiding the left column on default

By clicking a menu icon i am displaying the left navigation over the main content, and click a cross on the left col to hide it.

But once I close the left-col when I resize to desktop - the left col stays visible and I want it to be forced back.

Thanks

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: don't add style use a class and define styles for different @media queries

Comment: Or remove all the styles once you are done using `document.getElementById("left-col").removeAttribute("style")` to reset them to CSS defaults (do this in your `hideFunction` instead of the line thats in there). But to be honest, an average user does not resize their windows like you and me would :)

Comment: as told before, work with classes. remove the "hidden-xs" on click and add it on x-click.

Comment: I am unsure of what you mean by use a class? I have classes attached to the div - on for the media query under 767 and one for above this? Can explain a little bit more? Thanks

Comment: The idea would be to not directly set the `visible` property in CSS, but instead just add/remove a class, perhaps `lg-menu-hidden` then in your CSS media query for "large" views you could set `lg-menu-hidden` to be `visibility:hidden` but in other sizes, `visibility:visible` so that the menu would still be visible even when "hidden" according to the "X" close button.